# Increment/Decrement Data Extension field when Cloudpage is loaded

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage

I'm aiming to have Ampscript on a Cloudpage decrement a value in a specific data extension field whenever the page loads. Eventually there will be further logic to determine which of two values to change, but as a proof-of-concept/test I'm just trying to reduce both. Currently my test page is throwing an internal server error and fails to load. The full code is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<p>
placeholder
</p>
</body>
%%[
Var @ontrade, @email, @otdec, @emdec, @update1, @update2

Set @ontrade = Lookup('GB_Test_Kit_Count', 'Count', 'Type', 'ontrade')
Set @email = Lookup('GB_Test_Kit_Count', 'Count', 'Type', 'email')
Set @otdec = Add(@ontrade,-1)
Set @emdec = Add(@email,-1)

Set @update1 = UpdateData(
'GB_Test_Kit_Count',
1,
'Type',
'ontrade',
'Count',
@otdec
)

Set @update2 = UpdateData(
'GB_Test_Kit_Count',
1,
'Type',
'email',
'Count',
@emdec
)
]%%
</html>
```

The data extension is named GB_Test_Kit_Count. It has two columns, 'Type' and 'Count' and two records {ontrade, 50} and {email, 100}.

I'm guessing I've just screwed up the syntax somewhere, but I can't spot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problematic part is:

```
Set @otdec = @ontrade-1
Set @emdec = @email-1
```

You can use Subtract or Add like:

```
Set @otdec = Add(@ontrade,-1)
Set @emdec = Add(@email,-1)
```

The documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Add.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Subtract.htm

Comment: Made that change, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you doing it on the same page or on a new page? In other words, do you see "placeholder" text when you preview the page before publishing?

Comment: The preview doesn't render at all. It's just a grey screen with an endless loading icon.

Comment: It works on my end, the only possible solution that I think is trying the code in a new page because when you are working on the same page, because of cache issues, you still see the error.

Comment: Even when I copy the code to a new page it doesn't work. I thought it might be because the capitalization was different on the column names between the DE and the code, but I fixed that and it hasn't helped.

Comment: The data extension is named GB_Test_Kit_Count. It has two columns, 'Count' and 'Type' and two records {ontrade, 50} and {email, 100}. For that information, do you have right field with right value? it should be visa versa.

Comment: Unfortunately the error was in my original question and not in the Data Extension itself. Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/HFDW7QU in case you can spot anything I've missed.

Comment: I have exactly same data extension, with the same landing page code on your original post - after the change of Add function - but I don't get any errors. you can share your landing page screenshot also if you want. I am sorry I couldn't help.